# AWS Storage Gateway Connect Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been working on storage gateway since 2 weeks and noticing issue that whenever I'm going to connect to gateway it doesnt connect to me easily. It keeps giving the error connection page or this site cant be reached.

Has someone experience the same issue or I'm making some mistake.

Please answer at the earliest.

Comment: Please add the error stack trace

Comment: some how I am able to rectify the issue for current scenario that I forgot to add internet gateway to route table.

Thanks @neer17 to respond to the post.